# How to set a custom property in SVN (and get back all files having it set)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having a svn repository and am looking for the possibility to add a custom property to the files.

Later I want to get all the files containing the given property with the with a given value out of the repository.

Example:

I want to set a property of file called `label` having the value `123_ABC`.

Afterwards I want to get all files labeled "123_ABC" out of the repository.

Is this possible somehow?

I am using SVN and TortoiseSVN

Comment: It's second time, when I see **perverted method of use** custom SVN-properties. How did you all come about?

Comment: @LazyBadger We're trying to store [some metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_basic_info) that we've been [asking SVN to support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-1256) for more than 20 years now. Looks like we'll just have to do it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should understand that the **opposite direction of properties usage** implied
2. You can't get files with known only property-value, ignoring property-name, because different properties of the same file can have the same value
3. For your task (from property to files) you have to

   - use enumeration for all files in repository
   - apply `svn propget label` (or `svn proplist`) and verify result

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for all files with this property for all revisions? Yes, it is possible, but it is slow and not easy to do:

```
$ svn log --diff $REPO
```

This will do a diff of the log. When it sees a property difference, it will print out the property difference just like Subversion does when you diff a file. Of course, this is going to diff all files in your log which is very, very slow and produces a ton of output. You could use `grep` or something like that to find the version.

However, if you do this, you might as well run downstairs to Starbucks and grab a coffee while waiting. Heck, run down the block to that good coffee shop and sip a latte while you wait. Better yet, fly to Italy, run down to the coast, and sip a latte in a cafe while you wait. It's going to take a while.

If you find this discouraging you from this practice, good!

---

Or, are you merely searching for this property on particular files in your current working directory? If so, things aren't that bad:

```
$ svn plist --depth=infinity --verbose .
```

That will print out all the properties and their values for all files in your working directory. This will take a while, but not quite as long. You'll be lucky to make it downstairs to the Starbucks before it finishes. Again, I would pipe this to `less` and then do a search for the property I'm looking for. Since you're using Windows, save the output generated by this command, and use something like Notepad++ to search that file.

Comment: `svn proplist` or `svn pl` (for **really abbreviated** command), I think

Comment: All three work. I knew I could do it `svn proplist` or `svn plist`, but didn't realize that `svn pl`. Learn something everyday.